# Get duplicates of a HTML LI elements without using sort()

Tags: javascript

Let's say you have something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Then the problem is to find the first duplicate using JavaScript BUT you cannot use `sort()` method.

How would you do it?

Comment: Simply iterate and keep track of the values you have seen.

Comment: No, no; first: "*[how] would* you *do it?*"

Comment: Is this a challenge? It's maybe a good fit for codegolf

Comment: Sounds like someone's school homework...

Comment: @JamieBarker Nope. It was an interview question weeks ago.

Comment: @DanF If you didn't get the job, I wouldn't worry about it. Anyone that says "I want you to do something but only within parameters I set" can often mean they operate under the [laws of the Medes and Persians](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/law+of+the+medes+and+the+persians). Obviously you can't make that estimate from just one question but if that was what was being gestured to me during an interview, I'd reject any offer they gave me. "I want you to think outside the box, oh but I've moved the box inside a box that I've made and you must think within that."

Comment: @JamieBarker I agree. 1 question does not define a man. He told me skills were "junior." Oh well. Thanks.

Comment: @DanF "Opinions are like armpits. Everyone has more than one of them, and they all stink" ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
checkedArray = [];
elem = document.getElementsByTagName("li"); /* Would be better to have a direct reference to a specific element */
for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    var currentValue = elem[i].innerHTML;
    if(checkedArray.indexOf(currentValue) != -1) {
        // Found
    }
    checkedArray.push(currentValue);
}
```

Comment: I removed my down vote, and previous comment, based on your switch to plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use an object as an Hashmap :

```
// Values is an an hashmap storing all the values that have already been seen
var values = {};

// Get all the nodes
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].childNodes;


// Iterate over all the nodes, and check if its content has already been seen    
for (var node in nodes) {

  // If the hashmap already has a key equal to the innerHTML of the node return the current node
  if (values[node.innerHTML])
    return node;

  // Else set the hashmap key
  values[node.innerHTML] = true;
});
```

With [ECMAScript 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/find) you'll be able to do it in a more functional way:

```
nodes.find(function (node) {

  if (values[node.innerHTML])
    return true;

  values[node.innerHTML] = true;
  return false;
});
```

Comment: You won't have any issue by using innerHTML, it's just a string, two different HTML won't match even if they render the same way.
You can use innerText if you want or an equivalent, but this is not the interesting part here IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
var found = {};
for each li in lis {
    if (found[li.textContent]) {
        // found a duplicate!
    }
    found[li.textContent] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `ul` to array:

```
var list = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].childNodes).map(function (li) {
   return li.innerText;
})
```

Execute this function that uniqify a list:

```
 /**
  * @param list Mutable source
  * @return a list of duplicated indexes
  */
function uniqify(list) {
   var duplicatesIndexes = [];
   var b = list.length;
   while(c = --b) {
      while(c--) {
         if (list[b] === list[c]) {
            list.splice(c, 1); // Remove first duplicate
            duplicatesIndexes.push(c); // Save index of duplicte
         }
      }
   }

   return duplicatesIndexes;
}
```

See a result:

```
var list = [1, 1, 3, 6, 3, 8, 9, 5, 5, 5];
uniqify(list);
// <- [8, 7, 2, 0]
console.log(list);
// <- [1, 6, 3, 8, 9, 5]
```

If you want to do something with duplicated `li`s:

```
var liList = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].childNodes);
uniqify(list).forEach(function (index) {
   liList[index].style.borderColor = 'red';
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in jsfiddle. Says `document.getElementsByTagName(...)[0].childNodes.map is not a function`

Comment: @DanF What browser do you use?

Comment: Firefox, latest. System 64-bit. Win7

Answer (score -1):

I would loop through the `li` items and add their value to an collection. You can then check whether the value is in the collection or not.